# Add number of days to a date and calculate the end date?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

How can I calculate the number of days from a specific date?in other words add number of days to a date. I looked up NSCalendar and NSdate and could not find anything specific to that regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `-[NSCalendar components:fromDate:toDate:options:]` to compare dates, or `-[NSCalendar dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:]` to find a date that is a certain number of days from another date.